# Issue on running Twisted on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, twisted, zope.interface

First of all, I need to run twisted application on my server but what I get is this error

```
File "server2.py", line 1, in <module>
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
_checkRequirements()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/__init__.py", line 51, in _checkRequirements
raise ImportError(required + ".")
ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later.
```

So, this leads me to installed zope.interface. After running setup.py in zope.interface-4.1.2, I see this

```
Finished processing dependencies for zope.interface==4.1.2
```

I think I've updated it but when I run my twisted app, the same error appeared. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Which linux distro/AMI are you using?
did you check if you have multiple python versions installed?
maybe zope.interface requires c-binding library and you better of installing this package from apt-get/yum?

Comment: I'm not sure about multiple Python version but when I checked it using python -V command, it showed me only one version. And about c-binding library, could you tell the name of that package.

Comment: did you try to re-install twisted after installing the zope.interface lib?

Answer (score 0):

**on ec2**

If you see this message it means that zope.interface is available but has raised some reason why it might not work.

The code that imports zope.interface is shown below

```
# Don't allow the user to run with a version of zope.interface we don't
# support.
required = "Twisted requires zope.interface %s or later" % (required,)
try:
    from zope import interface
except ImportError:
    # It isn't installed.
    raise ImportError(required + ": no module named zope.interface.")
except:
    # It is installed but not compatible with this version of Python.
    raise ImportError(required + ".")
```

reinstalling the same version of zope.interface will probably not solve the issue but might be worth a shot. uninstall zope.interface first and then make sure there's no zope.interface stuff in you python site-packages directory before installing with `pip install zope.interface`.

The asker could try an alternative version of zope.interface but I think the issue is more likely related to the way python is installed on the system or that twisted is not installed correctly. You could try uninstalling `pip uninstall twisted` and then reinstalling twisted `pip install twisted`

**likely solution**

The easiest way to resolve the problem would be to run the application within a virtual environment and control which packages are installed. see the documentation here: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

for example you could install venv using pip and then install twisted into it

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install twisted
deactivate
```

you can try a different version of python than the system default with something like this

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
```

**AWS Lambda**

I ran into a similar issue when trying to run twisted on aws lambda.

I found that zope.interface could not be imported when installed using pip in a venv. It looked like some stuff was missing which meant it couldn't be imported normally as a module in my zip package but would probably work in the venv. removing it from site packages and replacing it with the source files solved my issue.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface/4.1.3#downloads

The current version at this time is zope.interface-4.1.3.tar.gz